# How can I get value from a special format string?

Tags: java, android, json, string

I am getting a string from web api like {"time":"08:05","code":"CSTM","name":"MUMBAI CST"} , this String is not convertible to   JSONObject , for this reason I am unable to get value from the string. How can I get value from the string?

Comment: this String is not convertible to JSONObject ... why ??

Comment: give ur code that you used to convert the above string to json?

Comment: Thank you all. I have found the solution. The text was JSON but it was my mistake .

Answer (score 0):

```
           link = new URL("The url");
           InputStream in = link.openStream();
          LoadRegistration_Api(in);

            protected void LoadRegistration_Api(InputStream json)   
                                     throws IOException, JSONException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                json));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());

        if (jobj.has("time")) // handle Se_wesam

        {
            Result = jobj.getString("time");

        }

        if (jobj.has("code")) // handle Se_wesam

        {
            UserId = jobj.getString("code");

        }

    }
}
```

Try this one i think it will help